# ParseException No result found for query

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I have a Table "User" in cloud with fields username,Longitude,Latitude. I am loged in as a user. And i want to retrieve record of specific ID in Welcome Activity. I have followed parse.com docs,Very helpful. I did as it is mentioned in docs for retrieving record but it gives me error ParseException No result found for query.
Here is my code for the query. Am i doing it right? Correct me if i am wrong. Please!

```
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    query.getInBackground("P0WcLeIgsm", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                String username = parseObject.getString("username");
                String longitude = parseObject.getString("Longitude");
                String latitude = parseObject.getString("Latitude");

                tv1.setText(username);
                tv2.setText(longitude);
                tv3.setText(latitude);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error"+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ParseUser.getQuery()
```

Rather than

```
ParseQuery.getQuery("User")
```

User does not work like a regular Parse table

edit-

You probably also want to change

```
new GetCallback<ParseObject>
```

to

```
new GetCallback<ParseUser>
```

In theory you don't have to since ParseUser extends ParseObject, but you get all the helper functions from ParseUser such as getUsername(), which you should prefer to getString("username")

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much fellow human being. May God bless you :)
Can you guide how to retrieve all data of User table to a list? Please!

Comment: I wish if i could +1 you but unfortunately i have less reputation

Comment: didn't help(( I used this workaround:  ParseQuery<ParseUser> localQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
            localQuery.whereEqualTo(KEY_USER_ID, contactId);
           try {
                             List<ParseUser> user = localQuery.find();
             catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }